# How to convert JSON-LD to JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, converters, json-ld

I want to Convert JSON-LD file to JSON in PHP.

Can anyone tell me, what is the procedure/steps should be done to do that? Or any API?

Comment: isn't JSON-LD already JSON? Can you show an little example to clarify your question?

Answer (score 1):

JSON-LD is a subset of JSON for encoding Linked Data in JSON (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-LD)). If you are asking how to decode JSON in PHP, have a look at [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) - this works fine with JSON-LD as well, as it is a subset.